# My .odb database spikes the CPU in OpenOffice and LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, database

my database is in .odb format, and it does not work in 9.1, 10.04, 10.10, openoffice OR 11.04 beta libreoffice but works in xp, w7 and fedora 14

The biggest issue i'm facing is that it takes minutes to move from one record to another 
spiking the processor at 100%.  I tested this on 3 different machines and they exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: Please remove as much as possible from the odb file and file a bug with the file attached.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).